# Frame offset with google map in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have some problems using google maps into column in my twitter bootstrap based new website. I'm using geocomplete script from unilabs.

The script don't diplay error on javascript console but the maps in the frame is not right ... there is an offset between the map and the frame. If y try to move it, the map will respond, but the offset stay the same.

I have try to add "max-width: none;" in the stylesheet for the map, but it stay the same.

Theres a print screen here : [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDYV5.png)

Can someone help me ?

I work with this script without problems in other website without boostrap.

Thank you and have a nice day
Greetings from switzerland